# Patch Request in Node Js is not working even after feeling all the required field

Tags: node.js, rest, express, mern

I am trying to update the database using patch request. I am providing two data from postman thai is email and complaintStatus. I am extracting it from body. I am using email to find the user and complanit
status to update the field complaintStatus. **Even after feeling both data it is giving {} as a response**

```
{}
```

Code

```
router.patch("/updateStatus", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {email,complaintStatus} = req.body;
    if (!email) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Plz Filled the data" });
    }
    const userData = await Complaint.findOne({ email: email });
    userData.complaintStatus = complaintStatus;
    const result = await Complaint.save();
    res.send({message : 'updated succesfully'});
    
  } catch (error) {
    res.send(error);
  }
});
```

Input

```
{
    "email":"nitish@nitish.com",
    "complaintStatus": "Solved"
}
```

Comment: Can you run the application in debug mode and add a breakpoint at the beginning of the function to make sure the code posted in question is executed?

Comment: **Even after feeling both data it is giving {} as a response** Your database or form (req.body)

Comment: I don't know whether it is from db or req.body but when i console log body it is showung correct